# gl-react-native not displaying image on physical iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, webgl

I'm trying to get the saturation example from gl-react:
[Contrast/Saturation/Brightness example](https://gl-react-cookbook.surge.sh/saturation)
working on an iphone, but for some reason the image only displays on an iOS simulator and not a real device.

This is what is shown on an iphone SE simulator running iOS 10.3 (Everything works perfectly, as in the example).
[image]
This is what is shown on an *actual* iphone SE running iOS 10.3
[image]

And this is the code

```
 /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Shaders, Node, GLSL } from 'gl-react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Slider
} from 'react-native';
import { Surface } from 'gl-react-native';

const shaders = Shaders.create({
  Saturate: {
    frag: GLSL`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec2 uv;
  uniform sampler2D t;
  uniform float contrast, saturation, brightness;
  const vec3 L = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
  void main() {
    vec4 c = texture2D(t, uv);
    vec3 brt = c.rgb * brightness;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(
      vec3(0.5),
      mix(vec3(dot(brt, L)), brt, saturation),
      contrast), c.a);
  }
  `
  }
});

export const Saturate = ({ contrast, saturation, brightness, children }) =>
  <Node
    shader={shaders.Saturate}
    uniforms={{ contrast, saturation, brightness, t: children }}
  />;



export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  state = {
    contrast: 1,
    saturation: 1,
    brightness: 1
  }

  render() {
    const { contrast, saturation, brightness } = this.state;

    const filter = {
      contrast,
      brightness,
      saturation
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.header}>
          SaturateGL
        </Text>
        <Surface style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}>
          <Saturate {...filter}>
            {{ uri: "https://i.imgur.com/uTP9Xfr.jpg" }}
          </Saturate>
        </Surface>
        <Slider
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={4}
          step={0.01}
          value={ contrast }
          onValueChange={ contrast => this.setState({ contrast }) }>
        </Slider>
        <Slider
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={4}
          step={0.01}
          value={ saturation }
          onValueChange={ saturation => this.setState({ saturation }) }>
        </Slider>
        <Slider
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={4}
          step={0.01}
          value={ brightness }
          onValueChange={ brightness => this.setState({ brightness }) }>
        </Slider>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

[Repo Here](https://github.com/JBriggs666/saturateGL)

I'm running

- gl-react@3.13.0
- gl-react-native@3.13.0
- react-native-webgl@0.70

and react-native-webgl is set up properly (I've linked the libRNWebGL.a and removed the libGPUImage.a in xcode as per the install instructions).

I'm quite new to react-native, so probably I've done (or worse yet, not done) something, which is a bit daft.  But if anyone can help point out why this is happening, I'd be most grateful.  This is really annoying me.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @user3075259 I have same problem, Have you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @Priya No, sorry, I never did.  I think one of the libraries gl-react was using was still under development at the time I posted this, and not all functionality had been implemented (If I remember rightly, I could be wrong), so I don't know that has changed.  I also didn't try the code ESA2012 posted below, as I'd given up on the project by that time, so I don't know if that works.  I no longer have my apple developer account either, so I can't try it out. I'd give that a shot and upvote them if it does, other than that maybe post an issue on the gl-react git.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `{{ uri: "https://i.imgur.com/uTP9Xfr.jpg" }}` to `{{ image : { uri: "https://i.imgur.com/uTP9Xfr.jpg" }}}` or `{{ image: "https://i.imgur.com/uTP9Xfr.jpg" }}`

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's quite explanatory itself, search for string, substitute that part of code with first or second option. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be you forgot to style the surface ? It took me long days to recognize that mistake

Comment: This should be Comment, not an answer.